# Github - contribution not showing even mail and username are set

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-config

I've read lot of similar questions but nothing helps.
I set user name and email correctly, even made my repo public and still contributions are not shown on Github page...
When I check my repo directly I can see new changes but even this it is still showing that changes were made couple hours ago.

To verify:
my repo:

```
https://github.com/geborskimateusz/mini-microservices
```

git configs:

```
mateuszgeborski@macbook-pro mini-microservices % git config --global user.name
geborskimateusz
mateuszgeborski@macbook-pro mini-microservices % git config --global user.email
mateuszgeborski@gmail.com
```

remote url

```
mateuszgeborski@macbook-pro mini-microservices % git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:geborskimateusz/mini-microservices.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:geborskimateusz/mini-microservices.git (push)
```

why is that?

I am doing it always the same:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

still contribution graph is not updated.

Comment: "but even this it is still showing that changes were made couple hours ago" Please show us what that part means. What's the actual direct phenomenon that concerns you?

Comment: I dont see this changes on contribution graph.

Comment: Have you actually pushed from your computer to the remote at github? Please, try to pose this as a reasonable question. Tell us _what_ you did, exactly. Tell us what you _expected_ to have happen as a result, and what _did_ happen, and how you know.

Comment: Yes.. I've done it as always. Just edited question.

Comment: Apart from the contribution graph, does the actual pushed commit appear on github?

Comment: yes it is pushed

Answer (score 2):

Have you given it some time? Such things are usually handled in bulk using a cron system. I'm assuming you are talking about the graphs in your profile.

Comment: Weird but true. I pushed empty commit from my second laptop and graphs were updated like you said in bulk mode. I looks something was hanging or cahcing.

Comment: I think this is a key thing to recognize and should probably be documented by GitHub.  My graph did not update until I made a new commit after adding the email address with which I had been making contributions.